# How do I use JavaScript Traverson HAL $all meta selector?

Tags: javascript, spring-data-rest, hateoas, hal, hal-json

Per the [JavaScript Traverson HAL documentation](https://github.com/traverson/traverson-hal#the-all-meta-selector)

> For embedded arrays you can additionally use the meta selector $all,
> which operates on embedded documents: If you pass ht:post[$all] to the
> follow method, you receive the complete array of posts, not an
> individual post resource. A link relation containing $all must only be
> passed as the last element to follow and it only works for embedded
> documents. Futhermore, it can only be used with get and getResource,
> not with post, put, delete, patch or getUri.

However, when I call:

```
    traverson
        .from("http://localhost:8080/api")
        .follow("cars[$all]")
        .getResource(
            function(error, document) {
                console.log(document);
        });
```

The browser console logs an empty array for `document`. The HAL response at `http://localhost:8080/api/cars` is:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "cars" : [ {
      "id" : 1,
      "name": "hotrod",
      "_links" : {
          "self" : {
             "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/cars/1"
          }
      }
    },{
      "id" : 2,
      "name": "junker",
      "_links" : {
          "self" : {
             "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/cars/2"
          }
      }
   }]
   },
    "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/cars"
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/profile/cars"
    }
  }
}
```

Why does my call to `.follow("cars[$all]")` result in an empty array instead an array of car objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to follows the cars link and then reference the cars array:

```
    traverson
    .from("http://localhost:8080/api")
    .follow("cars")
    .follow("cars[$all]")
    .getResource(
        function(error, document) {
            console.log(document);
    });
```

I thought that `cars[$all]` was following to the `cars` resource and `[$all]` retrieved the embedded array of cars.